# Predict upcoming coordinates

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

Given sequences of points that define similar lines amongst each others, e.g:

[image]

Where the blue lines are similar to each other, given the red point sequence **and assuming that it will follow the same behaviour as the blue ones**, I want to be able to determine what are the next red points.

Therefore my question is three fold: i) Is it possible to use machine learning approaches to address this problem? ii) Should I use machine learning approaches to address this problem? iii) Which known machine learning approaches are most suitable to address this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

An RNN might work for this :

1. Lines have a "sequence of points"
2. Network should "learn" that points tend to shift towards left (as Y increases) and should be able to apply similar shift for prediction of X for a given Y

An example : [Prediction of points for a Sin Wave](https://fairyonice.github.io/Understand-Keras's-RNN-behind-the-scenes-with-a-sin-wave-example.html)